# problem in downloading vlc

Tags: 12.04, package-management, vlc

i am new to ubuntu 12.04
i am facing a lot of problem while installing vlc in my laptop
every time i try to install it i get an error that the packages are broken.
i have tried repairing, cleaning and removing the packages and also reinstalling it but all in vain.

i tried installing all packages manually but the same problem occured

```
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-nox
```

i tried installing vlc using soft ware center but it showed the following error

```
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
 Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but 4:0.8.9ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
 Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but 4:0.8.9ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
 Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.5 is to be installed
 Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.4.8-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
 Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
 Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4 is to be installed
 Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4 is to be installed
 Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
 Depends: libtar0 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libxcb-keysyms1 (>= 0.3.8) but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3.dfsg) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4 is to be installed
```

vlc nox shows following error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

vlc-nox: Depends: liba52-0.7.4 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but 4:0.8.9ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
Depends: libavformat-extra-53 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but 4:0.8.9ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but 4:0.8.9ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.17-93ubuntu4 is to be installed
Depends: libcddb2 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libdvbpsi7 (>= 0.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libebml3 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.8.0) but 2.10.93-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.4.12-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.8.1-10ubuntu8 is to be installed
Depends: libgnutls26 (>= 2.12.6.1-0) but 2.12.23-1ubuntu4 is to be installed
Depends: libmatroska5 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libmpcdec6 (>= 1:0.1~r435) but 2:0.1~r459-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
Depends: libmpeg2-4 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libncursesw5 (>= 5.6+20070908) but 5.9+20130608-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
Depends: libpostproc-extra-52 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but 4:0.8.9ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
Depends: libresid-builder0c2a but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libsidplay2 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libsmbclient (>= 3.0.24) but 2:3.6.18-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.1-10ubuntu8 is to be installed
Depends: libswscale-extra-2 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but 4:0.8.9ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
Depends: libtwolame0 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libudev0 (>= 147) but 175-0ubuntu9.4 is to be installed
Depends: libvcdinfo0 (> 0.7.23) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libx264-120 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libxml2 (>= 2.7.4) but 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.0.2) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

@avinash
i tried the first command and got this

> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
>   W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/lucid-bleed/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
>   W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_binary-amd64_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

Comment: plz post the error report.Did you try `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: YES I DID.its been really frustatiing now.every time i do something it saysthat the packages are broken.

Comment: After listening everything , the only easy way you got is to use "Synaptics" , if you have it well and good , otherwise open Ubuntu-Software-Ceter and search for it, after installing synaptics seach for vlc and install everything it selects , including other dependencies . it will definitely work and please be careful while using synaptics.

Comment: @Sushantp606 i tried to install synaptic package manager too but it said that irs not available in my source code

Comment: possibly as of now you have lost most of the libs, unfortunately its hard to recover each of them , you can do it manually with the consideration of error log, it will take a lot of time and work, so re-installing it is a better option , and at the time of installation connect to internet  check to install third party SW and update then everything work for sure. I know its not the solution but it wont waste your time , cos as suggested by avinash you have done everything.

Comment: sso could u let ma knw wt m i supposd to do?..which way shud i go nw?

Comment: plus there are many things in my software centr wich r nt supportd ;the sources of wich rnt availble wt shud i do?

Comment: @Seth i had tried almost all of the steps written under that answer....nothing helpful happened

Answer (score -1):

Try these commands on terminal,

```
sudo rm -fR /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo sh -c "echo 'Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: \"(.save|.distupgrade)$\";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99ignoresave"
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-nox
```

Comment: plz post the reason for -1?

Comment: i didnt mark -1 to your ans.

Comment: what error did you got after trying `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: plz post the errors in pastebin and provide the link here.

Comment: @sonakshi i updated my answer plz see it.

Comment: i tried the first 2 commands but nothing happens.the terminal asks for my password  and then goes blank.my laptop's name appears for the next command